# Using a subdomain to send email through Google Apps without migrating email from primary domain

Tags: subdomain, mx-record, g-suite, bulk

Is it possible to set up email through Google Apps such that a single box, such as info@mailer.mydomain.com, can be used for bulk email without having to migrate all company email across to Google services and if so what would the MX records have to look like to achieve this split?

The desired end result would be that a single email created as a subdomain such as info@mailer.mydomain.com would be sending to an opt-in mailing-list through the Google account but the regular company email accounts would remain under their current hosting provider using the regular @mydomain.com format.

If this can't be done, are their any services that can offer something like this?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is properly configure MX records. If you have standard MX configuration in place then probably following configuration should be sufficient to achieve what you want:

Add new records, e.g:

```
mailer.mydomain.com IN MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
mailer.mydomain.com IN MX 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
mailer.mydomain.com IN MX 10 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

And leave your current config in place:

```
mydomain.com IN MX 10 your.mail.server
```

The new configuration will not affect your current config. All mails to @mailer.mydomain.com will go through Google, while mails to @mydomain.com will go to your current mail server.

Please verify whether MX records are correct for you GApps. I copied them from my old setup and they might be no longer relevant.

You can find more information about MX for GApps here: 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en

Also you have to remember that MX configuration is one thing, second is domain verification, so probably you will have to add some special CNAMEs, but this will be provided during domain registration in GApps.